# no effect happening to the program when i am putting r=NULL in function ins()

Tags: c, data-structures, binary-tree

While working with the pointers we are working on address, right?

So when a `struct node pointer n` is passed to `t(struct node *t=n)` and later if `t` is assigned `NULL` shouldn't `n` also become `NULL`?

ps-: it's a program of a binary tree

````
#include<stdio.h>   //check at third line of ins() function
#include<stdlib.h>
struct node{
int data;
struct node* left,*right;
};
struct node* n(int dat){
struct node *x=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
x->data=dat;
x->left=NULL;   x->right=NULL;
return x;
};

void ins(struct node* n,struct node* r){
    struct node* t=r,*y=NULL; //ok so when i put r=NULL in this next line should this block of memory go 
    //r=NULL;                  //NULL
    while(t!=NULL){
        y=t;
        if(t->data>n->data)
        {
            if(t->left==NULL)
                {t->left=n;
                    t=NULL;
                }
            else
            t=t->left;
        }
        else {
            if(t->right==NULL){
                t->right=n;
                t=NULL;
            }else
            t=t->right;
        }
    }

}
void inorder(struct node* n){
if(n!=NULL){
    inorder(n->left);
    printf("%d  ",n->data);
    inorder(n->right);
}}

void main(){
    struct node *a,*b,*c,*d,*e,*f,*g,*h;
    a=n(32);    b=n(20);    c=n(100);   d=n(16);
    e=n(25);    f=n(50);    g=n(144);   h=n(19);
    a->left=b;  a->right=c;
    b->left=d;  b->right=e;
    c->left=f;  c->right=g;
    ins(h,a);
    inorder(a);
}```
````

Comment: `//r=NULL;`  this is local to function `ins`, making changes to `r` inside `ins` will not have any effect on other functions (when enabled)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `struct node* t=r` you are creating a new and independent variable `t` that *points* to the same location as `r` (lets call that A).

This means any changes to `*r` are reflected in `*t` as they both *point* to the same location A.

when assigning NULL to `r`, the `t` variable still points to location A, but `r` no longer does.

A small example:

```
int A = 0;
int *r = &A;
int *t = r;
// *r==0, *t==0, point to same location
*r = 55;
// *r==55, *t==55 (same location)
r = NULL;
// *t==55 (*r is no longer valid as r is NULL)
```